# Why my prepared statement doesn't work, while regular statement work in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2, prepared-statement

I have a strange behavior when I try to use a following query with PreparedStatement

Query itself is following:

```
SELECT 
    CASE  
        WHEN TYPE LIKE '%Linux%' THEN 'Linux' 
        ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
    END AS OS, 
COUNT(*) AS TOTAL 

FROM COMPUTERS.OS 

GROUP BY 
    CASE   
        WHEN TYPE LIKE '%Linux%' THEN 'Linux'
        ELSE 'UNKNOWN' 
    END
```

And it works well. But when I create query like following:

```
SELECT 
    CASE  
        WHEN TYPE LIKE ? THEN ?
        ELSE 'UNKNOWN'

    END AS OS, 
COUNT(*) AS TOTAL 

FROM COMPUTERS.OS 

GROUP BY 
    CASE   
        WHEN TYPE LIKE ? THEN ? 
        ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
    END
```

And set it accordingly

```
String os = "Linux";
ps.setString(1, "%" +  os  + "%");
ps.setString(2, os);
ps.setString(3, "%" +  os  + "%");
ps.setString(4, os);
```

It doesn't work and throw a following error:

> SQLCODE=-119, SQLSTATE=42803, SQLERRMC=TYPE
>   A column reference in the SELECT or HAVING clause is invalid, because
>   it is not a grouping column; or a column reference in the GROUP BY
>   clause is invalid.

Somebody can me explain please what's wrong with my PreparedStatement?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might have to do with parameters and how DB2 determines if the `group by` clause is identical to the columns in the `select`.  A simple work around is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT OS, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL 
FROM (SELECT os.*,
             (CASE WHEN TYPE LIKE '%Linux%' THEN 'Linux' 
                   ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
              END) AS OS
      FROM COMPUTERS.OS os
     ) os
GROUP BY OS;
```

For the wildcard version, you would only put the wildcards in once and the compiler should accept the query.

Comment: Hi, thank you! You solution is working but for few Types only, when I send more then 400 parameters, I mean there are 400 instances of 'when type like ? then ?' I get error -302 -302
THE VALUE OF INPUT VARIABLE OR PARAMETER NUMBER position-number IS INVALID OR TOO LARGE FOR THE TARGET COLUMN OR THE TARGET VALUE All parameters which I pass are strings, from another question I get that limitation can be around 2000 parameters. What can cause such error now?

Comment: ok, solved it with cast(? as VARCHAR(500)) instead of ? Thank you again